# CASE statement in WHERE Clause of SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

I want to write a query that constructs the WHERE clause at runtime based on a condition. Here is what I want to do.

```
SELECT name from data_table WHERE 
CASE
WHEN input_data = location THEN <where condition should be based on location>
WHEN input_data = college  THEN <where condition should be based on college name>
```

How do I go about doing this? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible how about giving it a try

Comment: Yes! Your syntax is very correct. Go ahead with this.

Comment: @ Khalid Junaid : Tried. Not working. Was looking for the proper syntax.

Comment: @RitwikDey see [`demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/022d76/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT name 
  from data_table 
 WHERE 
   CASE
     WHEN input_data = location and name like 'B%' THEN 1
     WHEN input_data = college and name like 'C%' THEN 1
   END = 1
```

Add your conditions instead of the `name like 'B%'` and `name like 'C%'` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name from data_table
WHERE (input_data = location AND condition based on location)
   OR (input_data = college  AND condition based on college name)
```

Comment: input_data is not a table field. It is a variable that holds user input.